# How can i create image and link button from code (java) in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

Android view is in xml file, and we can drag n drop controls to it, but now i want to create image and link buttons from a while loop in java, it means we have to develop interface part from backend, how can we do so?

Comment: Good go ahed. Can you explain what you did yet:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageButton inherits from ImageView and has its own properties compared to Button properties.

you can check properties here,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Make your activity implement OnClickListener, then in OnCreate() or after that event. use ,

ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this); or 
//ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtnid)
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
in onClick() function you can handle the click event
```